# Get memory usage of a unit in journald

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

I have some units in systemd that I want that they log the memory usage of themselves in their logs(where I can check them using journald). Is systemd can do this automatically and log the memory usage in a predefined period in journald log file? If not, what is the simple way to do this in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

No, systemd cannot do this.

A privileged process can periodically sample page table entries in /proc/PID/. This way you can easily monitor the memory usage of stack/heap with the granularity of a page size.